# Same code in 2.3 is not working with Magento 2.3.3 version

Tags: php, magento, magento-2.3

This is code was working fine with Magento 2.3, but is not with 2.3.3

Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Search\Helper;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;

class Data {

    protected $dataHelper;

    protected $view;

    public function __construct(
        \Namespace\Module\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\View $view
    ) {
        $this->dataHelper = $helper;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function afterGetEscapedQueryText(
        \Magento\Search\Helper\Data $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $return = '';
        if(QueryFactory::QUERY_VAR_NAME == "q") {  
            $return = " data-id='exampleid_p1'";
        }

        return $result . $return;
    }
}
```

Screenshot of Frontend issue.
[image]

What has been changed in Magento 2.3.3 that I started facing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure this was working for `2.3`. The name of the function `afterGetEscapedQueryText` implies that it should be used like a *filter* for *escaped query text* which I believe is the `value` of the input. Is this filter function documented to actually see it's behavior?

Comment: Yes, working fine for 2.3 version.
No documentation of this function.

Answer (score 2):

Will it help if you change it to:

```
$return = ' data-id=\'exampleid_p1\'';
```